# Trigger modal shown for React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals - I am looking for a way to find the trigger event for 'shown.bs.modal' and not 'show.bs.modal'.

I don't see any documentation on some of the bootstrap modal events: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

```
var NewPerson = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return { showModal: false };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    // removed irrelevant code
  },

  close: function(){
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  },

  open: function(){
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  },

  submit: function(e) {
    // removed irrelevant code
  },
  render: function() {
    var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
    var ButtonInput = ReactBootstrap.ButtonInput;
    var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;

    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          className="pull-right bottom-20"
          bsStyle='success'
          bsSize='large'
          onClick={this.open}
        >
          Create New Person
        </Button>

        <Modal id="new-person-modal" show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Create a New Person!</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <form id="new-person-form" onSubmit={this.submit} accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="author" name="author" ref="author" placeholder="Author (First + Last)" required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <ButtonInput
                type="submit"
                value="Submit"
                bsStyle="success"
                bsSize="large"
                onSubmit={this.submit}
                disabled={this.state.disabled} />
            </form>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<NewPerson url="/person" />, document.getElementById('person-new'));
```

I even tried to hack it by just doing it in jQuery off to the side, which also isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new-person-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('modal displayed');
    // now can execute dynamic JS
  });
});
</script>
```

Any idea how to trigger the 'on shown' event?  I can't find anything in the react-bootstrap source either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a proper way to do this: use the onEntered event.

```
<Modal
  onEntered  = { function(){ console.log( "Modal is Shown" ) }}
>
```

This event is called when the transition which shows the modal is finished.

There are 6 transition triggers in total:

```
<Modal
  onExit     = { function(){ console.log( "onExit    " ) }}
  onExiting  = { function(){ console.log( "onExiting " ) }}
  onExited   = { function(){ console.log( "onExited  " ) }}

  onEnter    = { function(){ console.log( "onEnter   " ) }}
  onEntering = { function(){ console.log( "onEntering" ) }}
  onEntered  = { function(){ console.log( "onEntered " ) }}
>
```

Here's what they do:

```
onEnter     = Callback fired before the Modal transitions in

onEntering  = Callback fired as the Modal begins to transition in    

onEntered   = Callback fired after the Modal finishes transitioning in


onExit      = Callback fired right before the Modal transitions out

onExiting   = Callback fired as the Modal begins to transition out

onExited    = Callback fired after the Modal finishes transitioning out
```

At the time of writing, this solution is not documented. I'm submitting a pull request so hopefully they'll update the docs soon.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to create a non-visual component that will call a passed function on rendering and render this component somewhere inside Modal.Body:

```
render: function() {
    //...
    <Modal.Body>
      //...
      <Notifier onShown={this.onModalShown} />
      //...
    </Modal.Body>
    //...
}
```

UPDATE: 
This is how the Notifier component could be implemented:

```
var Notifier = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.props.onShown();
    },
    render: function() {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you break that down a bit more?  I'm not sure I understand how this Notifier will work. Also, pretty new to React/JSX

Comment: Excellent!  And to help anyone else who might have this, make sure you add the function onModalShown() to the Modal.

Comment: A great solution to a problem that should not exist

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same issue and this is what I tried...

```
Class Modal extends React.Component {

        showModal(){
        let obj = this.refs.modal;
        //write the required code here
      }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="standard-content">
              <p><a className="btn" onClick={this.showModal}  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Modal popup</a></p>
        </div>
        <div ref="modal" className="modal" id="exampleModal" role="dialog" >
            <div className="modal-dialog">
              <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">      
                    <h4 className="modal-title">Header area</h4> 
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                   body goes here..               
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

As I am using ES6 so I went with the class approach. I created a container div for modal contents and gave a ref attribute for reference. Then on click of  tag I attached a handler which will trigger when the modal shows up. With the help of this.refs you can access the modal. Hope it helps you.